# Immersion in both ways yet not an isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i was wondering if it's possible for two total orders A and B that there exist two injective functions f and g such that f is an immersion of A into B and g is an immersion of B into A, yet $A\ncong B$.

I came up with $A=\mathbb{R},B=\mathbb{Q^{\geqslant0}}$ so $f:A\Rightarrow(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q^{\geqslant0}}$ and $g:B\Rightarrow[0,1)\cap\mathbb{R}$ but i am not sure it is correct at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=[0,\infty)$ and let $B=(0,\infty)$.$\;$Then

- $A$ can be order-embedded in $B$ via the map $a\mapsto a+1$.$\\[4pt]$

  $B$ can be order-embedded in $A$ via the map $b\mapsto b$.

but $A,B$ are not order-isomorphic since $A$ has a least element but $B$ does not have a least element.

As regards your proposed example, it doesn't work; there is no injection of $A=\mathbb{R}$ into $B=\mathbb{Q^{\geqslant0}}\;$since $A$ is uncountable whereas $B$ is countable.